# Opendkim installation on Ubuntu Server 18.04 failing

Tags: 18.04, apt, software-installation, dkim

After installing virtualmin, opendkim installation (`apt install opendkim opendkim-tools`) fails in a following way:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up opendkim (2.11.0~alpha-11build1) ...
Job for opendkim.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status opendkim.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript opendkim, action "start" failed.
● opendkim.service - OpenDKIM DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Milter
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/opendkim.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: timeout) since Sun 2020-08-02 09:45:05 EEST; 9ms ago
     Docs: man:opendkim(8)
           man:opendkim.conf(5)
           man:opendkim-genkey(8)
           man:opendkim-genzone(8)
           man:opendkim-testadsp(8)
           man:opendkim-testkey
           http://www.opendkim.org/docs.html
dpkg: error processing package opendkim (--configure):
 installed opendkim package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 opendkim
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```